# Open AWS signed URL with FlatFileItemReader

Tags: amazon-s3, spring-batch

In Spring Batch I am trying to read a file with signed URL from AWS S3

This URL has the following parameters : `X-Amz-Algorithm=...&X-Amz-Date=...X-Amz-SignedHeaders=...&X-Amz-Expires=...&X-Amz-Credential=...&X-Amz-Signature=...` in query string

While opening this file the `FlatFileItemReader` calls the `exists()` method of the resource and thus operate a HEAD method to check if the response HTTP code is 200.

Instead it gets a 403 because the signed URL is only allowed for GET method :/

I am asking here if somone already encountered this issue and if you have any out-of-the-box solution.
I find out that my only solution will be to write my own reader, but the `FlatFileItemReader` do it so well, except for this case :D

NB :

- using GET method on the signed URL works well
- I already tested setting the `FlatFileItemReader` strict parameter to `false`

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I found kind of a workaround by overriding URLResource and always returning true for `.exists()` and `.isReadable()` methods

```java
/**
 * Automatically return true on <code>exists()</code> and <code>isReadable()</code> methods. This is made for signed <b>URL</b> that admit
 * only <b>GET</b> method while <code>exists()</code> and <code>isReadable()</code> use <b>HEAD</b> method and thus return a 403 instead of
 * expected 200 <b>HTTP</b> code. Used for instance in {@link FlatFileItemReader} which calls <code>exists()</code> and
 * <code>isReadable()</code> in <code>doOpen()</code> method.
 * 
 * @author pilak
 * @see FlatFileItemReader
 */
public class SignedURLResource extends UrlResource {

    public SignedURLResource(String path) throws MalformedURLException {
        super(path);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean exists() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isReadable() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Doing so the Reader can never verify if the underlying file is present. But at least the reader is well opened.

I think it's better to make the signed URL also allow HEAD method, but in case of this is not possible...